# c# error: is a 'field' but is used as a 'type' when trying to use while loop

Tags: c#, while-loop

I am going through the euler project with C# to learn the language and keep my coding skills sharp over the summer break (I'm a college student). So I am very new to the language. I tried to look for answers to this error but all the other similar questions I found don't deal with while loops. The code having an issue is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace EulerProblems
{
    class Problem2
    {
        List<int> fib = new List<int>();
        bool notAtLimit = true;

        while(notAtLimit)
        {
             //code to populate list of fibonacci series
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot write code directly within a class. You Need to write it inside a method, e.g.

```
private void Test()
{
    List<int> fib = new List<int>();
    bool notAtLimit = true;

    while (notAtLimit)
    {
        //code to populate list of fibonacci series
    }
}
```

Comment: Method, not function.

Comment: @Joe: Changed it, thanks. Although `function` is not really wrong, `method` is the more common term in OOP

Comment: @FlatEric "Technically" `function` would be wrong for this definition in certain languages (anything Visual Basic related) as a `function` is a `method` that returns a non-`void` type, whereas a `method` that returns a `void` type is a `sub(routine)`. Though, these are just semantics.

Comment: Okay, after reading your answer I figured out that when I made the Problem2 class, it didn't make a main method for me, even though I assumed it did.... haha such a noob mistake, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your code must be inside a method. You added code to the body of the class.

Answer (score 0):

you were almost there :) ... you need to put your code inside a method. and that method sits inside your class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace EulerProblems
{
    class Problem2
    {

        void SomeMethod()
        {
             List<int> fib = new List<int>();
             bool notAtLimit = true;

             while(notAtLimit)
             {
                  //code to populate list of fibonacci series
             }
        }
    }
}
```

That being said, get a c# book, and go through first 5-6 chapters ... doing every example ... and creating your own examples as well.

you need to get the concepts first ... otherwise you will keep getting these kind of blockers every now and then, and you don't want to come here and ask very very basic questions ... best of luck .... :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your code in a method:

```
public void Main() {
    List<int> fib = new List<int>();
    bool notAtLimit = true;

    while (notAtLimit)
    {
        //code to populate list of fibonacci series
    }
}
```